# Assign different weights for different displays

Tags: views

I am already guessing the answer is that it can't be done but any input on this would be much appreciated.

So I have my Content Type, say... **Cakes!** Now, I have a view named **ALL Cakes!** and they are sorted alphabetically on that.

I also have a view called **Popular Cakes**. Those can be sorted by weight and the *awesome* weight changer view integration.

Now, for some bizarre reason I also need a **Recent Cakes** view which is sorted in it's own way as the name reveals.

Now my question is, is there *any* way to add *another* weight for that view's use?

I know I can sort by date created but that would require going to every single node and manually changing the date; in short I am losing the drag and drop functionality Weight offers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out with the newest (dev) release of Draggableviews, I was able to use both modules (previously collided with each other) to sort my views choosing either method. So as long as I want to sort 2 views sharing the same content type, this will do. For 2+... well... I'll cross that bridge when/if I ever get to it :)

Answer (score 0):

Poking around in the Weight module, it seems they only allow you one weight per node.

However, you can just keep adding Sort Criteria to the View, based on fields you've added to the content type. So you could add a How Many Layers? numeric field and also sort by layers, in addition to weight and/or popularity and/or whatever.

Comment: Thanks, I knew that already, what I want to avoid is the annoyance of having to edit each and every node to manage their sorting. It's a pain in the ass when you have nodes with weights like : 49,50,51 and you want to add one between 49 and 50 for example, if you (and by you I mean the site's admin) hasn't foreseen that issue, he'll end up having to edit multiple nodes. *NOT* user friendly :)